# Understanding c++ block of code

Tags: c++, class

I was given a c++ main and have to code it so it works.

I am having some trouble understanding the code as I am a bit new to cpp.

Here is the code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Class::setAtribute("string"); 
  Class(Class::CONSTANT) << "starting up..."; 
}
```

Some questions:

1. How can the first line work with no variables? Is it static?
2. The second line is really strange for me, what I can make out is a Constructor that takes in a class constante and then prints it out somehow?

   If someone could explain me this bit of code it would be great!

   Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best answer is for you to go and look at the definition of `Class` which is most probably in one of the headers...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Thats what I thought at first, but I think this is homework and the OP has to design the class based on this piece of code (@kotoko is this correct?).

Comment: @Jesse yes that is true, I made an edit to better explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can the first line work with no variables? Is it static?

`Class::setAtribute()` must be a static function in class `Class`. A static function doesn't need an instance of a class (object).

> The second line is really strange for me, what I can make out is a Constructor that takes in a class constante and then prints it out somehow?

Right, it constructs an instance of `Class` passing `Class::CONSTANT` as the argument to `Class` constructor. For `Class(Class::CONSTANT) << "starting up...";` to compile there must be an overloaded `operator<<` in the form of:

As a member function of `Class` (David Rodríguez - dribeas):

```
<some_return_value_type> Class::operator<<(char const*);
```

or as a free-standing function:

```
<some_return_value_type> operator<<(Class const&, char const*);
```

or:

```
<some_return_value_type> operator<<(Class const&, std::string const&);
```

or, in C++11:

```
<some_return_value_type> operator<<(Class&&, char const*);
```

The second argument, in fact, can be anything that can be constructed from a string literal `char const[]`. Or, alternatively, `Class` can have a conversion operator to, say, `std::ostream&`, so that `std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream&, char const*)` is picked instead. Looking at `Class` definition and free-standing functions in its namespace must yield a definite answer.

Comment: a static function is just a function with static before it?

Comment: Yep, a class static function must have `static` in front of it.

Comment: ... and as David mentions, `operator<<` can be a member function of `Class`.

Comment: For the second question, there is no other code. The implementation is my job to do (it's an exercise). I think that your second option is what is wanted, can you explain a little more how do you apply a conversion operator and how do you direct it to stdout? Can you show an example?

Comment: You could implement it without conversion as a member function: `Class& operator<<(char const* s) { std::cout << s; return *this; }`.

Comment: I can't use your example. I have:

    // hpp
    class Class{
      public:
        Class& operator<<(char const* s);
    }

    // cpp
    Class& operator<<(char const* s) {
      std::cout << s; 
      return *this; 
    }

But get 

    error: Semantic Issue: Overloaded 'operator<<' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type

Answer (score 0):

the first line is declaring the `main` function, which is where the program starts running.  If you're used to Java or C#, yes, it's effectively static; it's not associated with an instance of any class.  Remember that in C++, you can have standalone functions that aren't even *part* of a class.  `main` is one of those.

The second line is calling a static method called `setAtribute` on a class called `Class`, and passing it a string argument.  It's not clear what the purpose of that line is, but as far as how it works, it's just an ordinary function call, not a constructor.

**Edit:**  I just realized that when you said "first line", you might have actually meant the line I called the "second" one.  In that case you're asking about the third line too.  Yes, that's constructing a temporary instance of the class, then calling its `<<` operator (presumably to print something).

Answer (score 0):

> How can the first line work with no variables? Is it static?

Most probably, you should go and check the headers for the definition of `Class` and verify, but I am 90% sure it is a static method call.

> The second line is really strange for me, what I can make out is a Constructor that takes in a class constante and then prints it out somehow?

You kind of have it. It most probably (again check the sources) creates a temporary object of type `Class` initialized with `Class::CONSTANT` (there is a constructor that matches the type of the static member `Class:CONSTANT`). Then `operator<<` is called on that temporary. In this particular case, `operator<<` is most probably implemented as a member function of `Class` that takes either a `const char*` as argument or something convertible from it, like a `std::string`.